# Redirect not working for blank user agent

Tags: redirect

I have a redirect rule in htaccess.  This usually works just fine but in this case the bot/hacker has a blank user agent.  The domlog shows,

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [30/Dec/2013:15:56:33 -0600] "POST /path/to/file.php HTTP/1.1" 301 426 "-" "-"
```

However the user is not actually being redirected.  I know this from the logs, because they are not subsequently being sent to the appropriate place.  I am assuming it has to do with the blank user agent but I am not sure.

My htaccess rule is,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^file.php$ http://www.example.com/otherfile.php [R=301,L]
```

Anyone know why this particular individual is not being redirected?  And if there is a way to get around it?

Comment: It's a bot. It doesn't have to follow the redirect if it doesn't want to.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know exactly why it's not being redirected, however, you can try to block all empty user agents with this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^$ [OR]
RewriteRule ^.* - [F]
```